# SpriteKit: How can I make my HUD following my camera?

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, swift4

I've initialized my camera and constraint it to my player // didMove(to view: SKView):

```
    self.camera = cameraNode
    self.addChild(cameraNode)

    let range = SKRange(constantValue: 0)
    let cameraConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, to: player)
    cameraNode.constraints = [cameraConstraint]
```

Here I initialized my control buttons for example the jump button:

```
let jump = SKSpriteNode(named: "...")
jump.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width*0.07, height: self.size.height*0.07)
jump.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.05, y: self.size.height*0.1)
jump.zPosition = 2
self.addChild(jump)
```

I handled the function the button calls with a UIGestureRecognizer. Now I want my control buttons to follow the camera. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the jump button as a child of the scene, add it as a child of your camera node. Just like other nodes, `SKCameraNode`'s children always follow the parent.

So instead of:

```
self.addChild(jump)
```

use:

```
cameraNode.addChild(jump)
```

Comment: If I do this, I can't press the jump button anymore. `let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = CFTimeInterval(0.0)
    longPress.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.longPressGesture(longpressGest:)))
    self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)`

Comment: This is how I have done it before but now this doesn't work anymore

Comment: do `self.view!` and see if the program crashes for you